# Android bottom navigation bar not displaying correctly when rotated

Tags: android

I currently have an issue with the bottom navigation bar when it is rotated:

[image]

Essentially, I need the bottom navigation bar to completely fill the bottom when it is rotated.

[image]

Here is my layout:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="6"
android:rowCount="6">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_rowSpan="6"
    android:text="@string/home" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_history"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/history"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_favorites"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/favorites"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_rowSpan="6"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_az"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/az"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_rowSpan="6"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="6"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/textColorPrimary"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

Any comments/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not supposed to be full width to begin with according to [design guideline](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-specs) from google. To look as its full width,just change the background color of your navigation view.

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
     android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
     app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"

     // .... />
```

Comment: @RobertoJosefAmparán-Frisby accept it as answer then :D